# How do I get an elevation value back from Bing elevationAPI using Java?

Tags: java

I attempted to get elevation data from the Bing elevationAPI using the following Java code:

```
public static void elevationAPI (double latitude, double longitude )throws IOException {
    int responseCode = 0;

    try{    
        URL url = new URL("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Elevation/List?points="+ latitude + "," + longitude + "&key=MyKey");

        HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];

        int n=0; 
        while( (n = in.read(buffer)) != -1){ 
            writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
```

However, I did not get any elevation values with this query.

My result is:

```
{
    "authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials",
    "brandLogoUri":"http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
    "copyright":"Copyright Â© 2015 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
    "resourceSets":[
        {
            "estimatedTotal":1,
            "resources":[
                 {
                     "__type":"ElevationData:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",
                     "elevations":[0],
                     "zoomLevel":8
                 }
             ]
         }
    ],
    "statusCode":200,
    "statusDescription":"OK",   "traceId":"b9dc9583749c42bab8f8e6ee04d7dba6|BN20130723|02.00.130.200|ak.t0.tiles.virtualearth.net"
}
```

Comment: Are you certain the location you tried is not at sea level?

Comment: I'm trying to get locations below sea level, is this my problem?

Comment: The documentation is vague. I can't spot any problems with your syntax however. Is it working for known locations above sea level?

Comment: Yes, it is working for known locations above sea level, Thank you for your help.